# I want to load local store in between the server response (making java script code synchronysed)

Tags: javascript, callback, synchronization, sencha-touch-2

> I have view page where am trying to display all organizations,which is
>   obtained by a server call..In order to feel the application responsive
>   , in between the server response I want to load all local store
>   items.. But server call is always executing first.. The code I
>   mentioned bellow..

```
initialize: function() 
{
    var me = this,
    st = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
         fields : [ {......................}]});
    me.callParent(arguments);  

    me.setStore(st);

    me.on({
        show  : me.onShow,              
        scope: me
        });   

},

onShow:function()
{
      var me = this;
      Ext.create('Ext.util.DelayedTask', 

      //call back function ,purpose : delayed exicution

          function () {
          me.DelShow(function(){
         _syncMgr.getOrgGroup(-1,0,5); // servercall
          });
          }).delay(500);
},  

DelShow: function(callback)
{

            orgStore = Ext.getStore('Organizations'),
            orgStore.load(function(records)
                {
                    var i=0,len = records.length,
                    for(;i<len;i++)
                    {
                        organization = records[i];
                        regId = organization.get('rg_id');
                        resStr = organization.Resources();                      
                        resStr.load({callback:function(resorces)
                         {
                            var i = 0,rlen =resorces.length,
                            obj = {},
                            obj.rg_id = str.boundTo.get('rg_id');

                        }
                           orgViStr.add([obj]);


                       });
                     }
                });
    me.lodorg(callback);

    },


lodorg:function(callback)

{
 callback();
 console.log("I don't know why this call back works first....");
 console.log("plz help me to work last....");     

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call You callback method after You load data from local store .

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is add the content from your local store to the list that is currently set in the view then refresh the list.

```
var localStore = something.getStore(),
entries = [];
localStore.each(function(entry){
    entries.push(entry.copy);
});
//me is the list that is set in the view
me.add(entries);
me.deselectAll();
me.refresh();
```

Hope that helps :)